# Warning: mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'mobileto'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to access a PHP database I created online using this URL

```
http://dns.com/data_api/connect.php
```

I have created the database and it has no username and password attached to it at the point of creation. When I try to check if the connect.php could establish a connection to the database I get this error

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'mobileto'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/mobileto/public_html/data_api/connect.php on line 11

Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'mobileto'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

This is the connect.php file

```
<?php
            $username = "";
            $password = "";
            $hostname = "localhost"; 
            $dbase ="mobileto_holo";

        //connection to the database
        //$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
        $con=mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$dbase); 
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { 
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
}
        // or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
        //echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";

    //$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
?>
```

Please what could be wrong?

Comment: No Username or Password? `:O` That's impossible. Try giving `root` as the default username.

Comment: "`localhost`"? On which machine is your database and from which machine are you trying to connect?

Comment: @deceze Join the discussion in my answer. Looks like the OP created the DB using cPanel and struggling.

Comment: @Praveen I'm trying to clarify *the question*, not join a discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Username or Password? `:o` That's impossible. Try giving `root` as the default username, instead of passing an empty string.

```
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost"; 
$dbase    = "mobileto_holo";
```

Comment: Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: @Blaze How did you know that you haven't set a username and password?

Comment: @Blaze Did **you** set up MySQL in your machine? Did you install and start? Or was it bundled with WAMPServer or something else?

Comment: You don't need to add a password to your mysql account, it's not possible to use it without username atleast. Password is optional but it's higly recommended to have one. @Blaze

Comment: @C0dekid You don't* need.

Comment: I created the database from the cpanel and no username or password was entered by me

Comment: Mysql was installed in cpanel which I created my database

Comment: @Blaze cPanel? Okay, in that case, try opening the MySQL Users from there and reset the password. **Definitely no way cPanel allows you to use MySQL DB without password.**

Comment: I created a new user with a password and assigned all the privileges to it

Comment: @Blaze You should actually add this as an answer to your own question. You don't get points for it, but it will help make this solution more prominent. This solved my problem, but what If I hadn't bothered to read all the comments? I had tons of other links to other threads on the same question, and almost passed this up. I might have taken much longer to find the solution.